# Error saving search page after adding filter rule to tab

Tags: coveo

I am setting up a search page, but I'm getting an error when hitting save on the tab component, after adding a filtering rule. If I remove the rule, it saves fine.

The rule is simple. just filter by a particular template type:

[image]

When saving the page in experience editor (not when clicking OK to the dialog) I see:

[image]

Looking at the Sitecore log, I can see the following:

```
27008 16:28:37 ERROR After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: {. Path 'scLayout', line 2, position 14.
Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
Message: After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: {. Path 'scLayout', line 2, position 14.
Source: Newtonsoft.Json
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParsePostValue()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.Requests.PipelineProcessorRequest`1.Process(RequestArgs requestArgs)
```

So it seems like something in the rule cannot be parsed as JSON?

Comment: This behavior is a bug in Sitecore itself that affects rule editor fields as well as other XML raw value field types. It was previously answered/documented: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/error-in-experience-editor-when-saving-rendering-with-image-field-rendering-para

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have run into a Known Issue with Sitecore. With 8.0 update 6 and 7, 8.1 update 1, and 8.2, there is an issue that prevents pages with rules from being saved in the Experience Editor.

There is a workaround, where you can edit and save the rules in the **Presentation** > **Details** section, or remove all of your rules before saving.

Here is a link to the [documentation](https://developers.coveo.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=33587260).

Hope this was of help!